# How to restart a neo4J 2.1.5 server from an unmanaged extension?

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to make an extension that will provide a REST endpoint to completely cleanup the data (In order to launch thorough automated tests)

Here is the GitHub of the plugin: https://github.com/Linkurious/neo4j-cleanup-addon

My issue lies there:

```
private Map<String, Object> cleanDbDirectory(GraphDatabaseService database) throws Throwable {
    String storeDir = config.getString(DATABASE_LOCATION_PROPERTY_KEY);

    database.shutdown();
    Map<String, Object> result = removeDirectory(storeDir);
    // TODO restart here
    return result;
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can check my old "cleandb" extension which lives [here](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-clean-remote-db-addon).

You don't have to restart the server, just the database inside it.

These days you don't really need it anymore because you can clean out the db with a simple cypher statement too (at least in test-environments)

```
MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
DELETE n,r
```

Comment: If you check my code, you will get that I mainly forked you addon ;-). For which I should thank you, by the way.

The API changed and the object you get from the context annotation is a GraphDatabaseService, and it doesn't have a start method.

As for the cypher query I don't think it clears labels and indexes too.

Comment: Then you probably have to use your own custom server and either inject something that wraps the database, or provide a method on your server to restart it. Like this one here: https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-in-memory-server

Answer (score 0):

You could also check out [RestTest](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-resttest), which has a REST method for clearing the graph, as well as other methods for automated tests.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That does help. However, this doesn't delete labels from the database, does it ?

Comment: nope, the only way to delete labels is to actually wipe out the db directory

Comment: Could it be possible to do that from within the plugin ?